# ERD mostly in text

Tags: erd, naming-convention

[image]

In `LaTeX` I can replicate database tables similar to the ones in the diagram below, but I do not want to deal with figuring out how to nicely draw the relation diagrams between the tables. Is there an accepted convention to denote the relations in text. For example, I do not need to put a picture of a key to denote `Primary Key`—PK would unambiguously do the job. Are there similar conventions to denote the relations between the tables?

Comment: Chen Style 1:N (one to many), 1:1 (one to one), M:N(many to many),      N:1(Many to one)

Comment: You can check at https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/